# Bounds on integral with arbitrary power of functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, general-topology, functions

Let $f,g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,1]$ be smooth or even analytic functions.
Consider the following integral:

$$\forall \ i_1,i_2 \in \mathbb{N}: \int_0^t f(s)^{i_1} \cdot g(s)^{i_2}ds$$

I would be interested in any bound (possibly the sharpest one) on that integral.

---

The integral becomes smaller for higher powers, hence I assume the bound to be something like
$$\sim \frac{t}{i_1+i_2}$$
but I am unable to prove it.

Comment: What if $f=g=1$?

Comment: Is it $\int_0^t$ or $\int_0^1$? In any case you shouldn't use $t$ both as a dummy variable of integration and an extreme of the interval.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. We can also assume that $f,g$ map in the open interval $(0,1)$ @RobertIsrael

Comment: Think of a bump function which is equal to it's max in $(\varepsilon, t-\varepsilon)$ - the bound of @RobertIsrael is still tight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bound is trivial but sharp:
$$\int_0^t f(s)^{i_1} g(s)^{i_2}\; ds \le t \left(\max_{s \in [0,t]} f(s)\right)^{i_1} \left(\max_{s \in [0,t]} g(s)\right)^{i_2}$$
with equality when $f$ and $g$ are constant.